# finding object reference in array by index

Tags: java

As the title says i'm trying to determine if a index/object exists by passing in a explicit index value and then searching for it in the array, determining if it exists, then if it exist,then returns the value/object reference there else returns null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nextPos -1; i++) {
            if (i == inIndex) {
            i = inIndex;
            return results[i];

            }
// here is what its supposed to do if it doesnt find one
return null;
```

nextPos is the companion variable for how many "slots" in a array they are filled.

inIndex is the explicit

In my code here I'm assuming it loops throught the entire loop and if i the current position is equal to the index it should set i to equal inIndex; then return whatever there but i just keep getting a null result

i have already confirmed that the array is full with 50 values

i dont know what i am doing wrong here
array results is a object reference holding array

update: nextPos is already set to equal the filled postions in array results

```
{


        if (this.nextPos < this.results.length){
            this.nextPos++;

    }  

    return nextPos;
```

inIndex is the index im searching for,
as said above im trying to find the index of a object in results array, using the InIndex i pass in whatever the value is, and then once found return the value contained at that index, if that index does not exist, return null

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nowhere in your code you are trying to find said reference in an array... You are not even checking said array. And this code up here is missing at least a closing curly brace... All your code (assuming the missing bracket is a typo) is doing is looping the size of `nextPos` and checking whether the position in said loop is the same as `inIndex` and then returning whatever is in that `results` array which is nowhere up here for us to understand... Please place all relevant parts of your code in your question.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Is `inIndex` an array index, or the value (reference) that you want to find.  (Your code implies that it is an array index ... which doesn't make a lot of sense.)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to find Object in array by index. Try with below code

```
public String findObjectByIndex(int indexToFind) {
    String[] names= {"name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6","name7"};

    try {
        return names[indexToFind];
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrayindexException) {
        System.out.println("The given index not found in the array");
    }
    return null;

}
```